# Instantiating a class based on a string value or grouping a set of classes without using an Interface

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, initialization

I have some code which receives a string - depending on that string is which class is instantiated e.g. if its "customer" it does new CustomerData() etc. There will be 10-30 different string values and each has an associated class that would need instantiating:

I did think of using a dictionary to resolve this:

```
  public IData data; //the classes are currently in an interface but this is looking impractical due to differing methods.

  data = dataLookup["dataType"];

  dataLookup = new Dictionary<string, **what data type is this?**>
        {
            { "customer", new CustomerData() },
            { "company", new CompanyData() }
            ...etc 10-30 rows... 
        };
```

The problem is i dont know how to set the datatype in the dictionary - i dont think adding all the classes to an interface  is the answer. Although the classes are all related (they are all "data" for the application), only about half the methods in each data class are the same, the rest of the methods are unique to each data class. I've read on Interfaces that i could just add the unused methods in each class and no-op them, but it does sound a bit messy.

What would be the cleanest solution to instantiate the correct class based on the string value?

Comment: Do `CustomerData` or `CompanyData` class constructors have parameters or not? If all constructors are parameterless, you can store the type in a dictionary, not the instance. And then use `Activator` to create an instance

Comment: The constructors of each data class do not have parameters. Could you explain these suggestions please, I'm a newbie to c#.Many thanks.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - i think you wrote an answer with Activator that has been removed? I was going to try it today - is it no longer recommended?

Comment: I can undelete it, and you can try, but I'm not sure that dynamic cast is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of you classes have parameterless constructors (according to comments), as an option you can manage a dictionary of `string` as a key and `Type` as value (instead of concrete instance).

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    { "customer", typeof(CustomerData) },
    { "company", typeof(CompanyData) },
};
```

And use it in the following way, get a type by key from a dictionary and create an instance of that type. But this instance has an `Object` type, since you can't use a type known at runtime during a compile time. The possible way here is use `Convert.ChangeType` and store the result in `dynamic` type variable

```cs
var type = dict["customer"];
var data = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
dynamic result = Convert.ChangeType(data, type);
```

Comment: Thanks yes it does work but i think i need a more concrete instance of the class to perpetuate through the code. The variable "data" is currently an interface "public IData data;" but i cant use Interface as each data object has different methods. I think I'm looking for an interface type solution without the restriction of matching methods that the interface contract dictates.

Comment: Actually "public dynamic data" works fine - i cant see any reason not to just use this as a dynamic object.

Comment: @m_finn Dynamic object can probably cause some runtime errors, because compiler can't check your code at compile type. But if you have a set of known methods for every data instance, it shouldn't be a problem:) You can approve an answer, if it solves your question

Comment: no, this seems to be working well - thanks for your support